# Superimposed hydrogen electron states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, quantum-information, electrons

I have been following an Edx.org course on Quantum Computing. The Prof. has started with a Hydrogen atom qubit, assuming that the electron can only be in the ground state and the first excited state.
Next he talks about superimposed electron states where there is probability of a measurement showing the electron in one or the other of the two states.
I have several questions about this:

(1) How does one create this superimposed state?

(2) If the electron was originally in the ground state, then put into this superimposed state, and measured to be in the excited state ... then
 Where did the Energy come from to put it into the excited state?

(3) The Prof also indicates that the superimposed electron state could be measured in any one of the infinite other superimposed state possibilities. How would one set up such a measurement?

Thanks for any clarity on this.

Comment: To raise a H atom to the 1st excited state is not a big problem, one can illuminate H atoms with photons from the Lyman series. Part of the photons will be scattered, and part absorbed, the absorptions leading to H atoms in the 1st excited state. So, you get the transformation: $ |H\rangle |ph \rangle \to \ \alpha |H_{n = 2} \rangle + \beta |H_{n = 1} \rangle |ph \rangle _{scattered}$.

Comment: just notice that you don't have a simple superposition $\alpha|H_{n=2}⟩+β|H_{n=1}⟩$, but there is a photon too.